# openCV 3.1.0 Cannot load .dat

Tags: python, opencv

I moved from python 2.7 to python 3.5

So, I had to use openCV 3.x.x.

The problem is that I cannot load SVM data.

For openCV 2.x.x, I could use

```
svm.load('filename')
```

However, for openCV 3.x.x, there is no load method.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182132/how-to-load-svm-data-from-file-in-opencv-3-1) article.

But I could not find a method,

```
cv2.ml.SVM_load()
```

I think 3.1.0 is latest version, and I use it.

```
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.1.0'
```

How can I load svm data?

Comment: this is a bummer: TypeError: can't pickle ml_SVM objects

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. Additional infos to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38956656/3524844):

Use the opencv master branch (currently 3.1.0-dev) of opencv

```py
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.1.0-dev'
```

there is the [method](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d2d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1SVM.html#a7b05db6110aec2246f2b31363937539c) you're looking for

```
SVM_load(...)
    SVM_load(filepath) -> retval
```

in the output of

```
>>> help(cv2.ml)
```

I use it in production with Python 3.4.3+.

Comment: did you compile by yourself? Where can I download 3.1.0-dev?

Comment: Yes, you need to clone the itseez/opencv repo from github. If you search online for "install opencv 3.1 with python3 on Ubuntu/Mac/etc" you will find some very good tutorials to compile opencv very simple and quickly. But make sure that you don't checkout other branches and stay on the master branch.